# How to display multiple hgt in 2d maps

Tags: c++, opengl, geography

Hi i have problem with multiple hgt files when i want to diplay them.
When i have one map it is not a problem. For example for 2d map i can remember vertex like
`vec2(i,j)*vec2(0.01,-0.01)`.

But i need to have more than one map. I need to use Equirectangular projection
So my question is how to transform i,j position from hgt file to Longitude and Latitude.
My idea is if we have file N45E016.

```
x = 44 + i/1201;
y = 16 + j/1201;
```

But i think this is wrong. Because x depends from y;
After i get x and y i can compute Equirectangular projection.
So my question is how to do this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = xmin + dx * i / (w - 1)
y = ymin + dy * j / (h - 1)
```

with:

```
dx = xmax - xmin
dy = ymax - ymin
```

`xmin`, `xmax` are the min./max. longitude of the tile (hgt file),
`ymin`, `ymax` are the min./max. latitude of the tile,
`w`, `h` are the width and height of the tile (number of samples along the longitude/latitude axis).

You may have to adapt slightly the proposed formula depending on whether the samples are replicated along the tile boundaries or not.